# Django Filter admin list by user group and

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-admin

Hi im really a noob at django.
Can i ask if there is anyway to filter list by user group?
When creating a user at admin, there is also choice for creating groups. After assigning these user to certain groups, i have another model e.g. Staff where Staff information is provided and is linked to the user. So very Staff must be  a user and also must be member of the group staff. I have already created a drop down menu at Staff Page for the list of users when creating a new Staff.

The  problem is that i cant seem to figure out how the list of users shown at staff page can be filtered according to the user group and also assignment since it should be OnetoOne relation w/ the user. So users who been used or is already linked to a certain staff will not show in that list again when creating a new Staff.

Im thinking of using Staff.model.count()? to do that and == the user to Staff User Group. but where should i out in order to customize it? please help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should write your own ModelAdmin, then unregister User and register User with UserAdmin with your custom behaviour. This way you can overwrite the queryset, forms etc.. Look at the ModelAdmin source code

```
class UserAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    # do stuff

admin.site.unregister(User)
admin.site.register(User, UserAdmin)
```

Comment: This goes in admin.py